# Help with Twitter ID_Str

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm really new on php and twitter oauth and I'm on my learning..
I'm confused when dealing with id_str

I want to know how to get id_str using oauth 
(on twitter client such as dabr, etc) you'll often see tweet time (posted 52 minutes ago, etc) and when you click it will got to single tweet page --live example http://twitter.com/#!/twitterapi/status/4917112329994240

I have no idea how to get/request this number "4917112329994240"

part of my code:

```
$consumer = new
OAuthConsumer(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,
OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET);   $sha1_method
= new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
    // user's token   list($oauth_token,
$oauth_token_secret) = explode('|',
$GLOBALS['user']['password']);  
$token = new
OAuthConsumer($oauth_token,
$oauth_token_secret);
    // Generate all the OAuth parameters needed   $signingURL =
'https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json';
$request =
OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer,
$token, 'GET', $signingURL, array()); 
$request->sign_request($sha1_method,
$consumer, $token);
    $header[1] .= ", oauth_consumer_key=\"" .
$request->get_parameter('oauth_consumer_key')
. "\"";   $header[1] .= ",
oauth_signature_method=\"" .
$request->get_parameter('oauth_signature_method')
."\"";   $header[1] .= ",
oauth_token=\"" .
$request->get_parameter('oauth_token')
."\"";   $header[1] .= ",
oauth_timestamp=\"" .
$request->get_parameter('oauth_timestamp')
."\"";   $header[1] .= ",
oauth_nonce=\"" .
$request->get_parameter('oauth_nonce')
."\"";   $header[1] .= ",
oauth_version=\"" .
$request->get_parameter('oauth_version')
."\"";   $header[1] .= ",
oauth_signature=\"" .
urlencode($request->get_parameter('oauth_signature'))
."\"";

$twtid =
$request->get_parameter('id_str');
```

didn't return any result

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers of Dabr.

To retrieve a single status from the API, use this call

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/4917112329994240.json?include_entities=true
```

You will, of course, have to sign your request with OAuth.